# Heavy number corruption in floating point division in Java?

Tags: java, floating-point, division

I have been trying to do something simple with java floating point division, have read several articles on some minimal changes on values but nothing like I am having below.

This is the expected:

```
float f = 1789773f / 1000000f;
System.out.printf("\n%.2f", f);

Outputs: 1,79
```

This is what happens when I work with variables:

```
int CLOCK=1789773;
System.out.printf("\n%.2f", (float)CLOCK/(10^6));

Outputs: 13410,48
```

What is going on? I had to use the literal '1000000f' instead of 10^6 to make it work. Also, I thought that casting the one of the division elements with (float) would set everything as float and I would not end doing integer math.

Comment: For reference: `^` is the bitwise exclusive or opreator and belongs to the [bitwise operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html).

Answer (score 3):

`10^6` is not a million. It's 12, because `^` is the bitwise xor operator rather than exponentiation.

Use `1e6f`, or just `1000000f`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this instead :

```
int CLOCK = 1789773;
float fclock = (float) (CLOCK/(Math.pow(10,6)));
System.out.printf("\n%.2f", fclock);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
float CLOCK=1789773f;
System.out.printf("\n%.2f", CLOCK/Math.pow(10,6));
```

**`OR`**

```
int CLOCK=1789773;
System.out.printf("\n%.2f",(float) (CLOCK/Math.pow(10,6)));
```

Try to use **`Math.pow(10,6)`**, it's working fine for me.